# can't find where div generate

Tags: jquery, css, html

please look at this Image Gallery
[image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.slider)

if you view page source you can see something like this

```
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 240px; width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/demos/img/travel/01.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/demos/img/travel/thumb-01.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/demos/img/travel/02.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/demos/img/travel/thumb-02.jpg" />
        </div>
```

but if you inspect page using google chrome you can see

```
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 240px; width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; pointer-events: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;"></div></div><div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 240px; width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;">
                <div style="width: 720px; height: 480px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; display: none; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
                <div data-p="150.00" style="width: 720px; height: 480px; top: 0px; left: -720px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; perspective: 150px;">
                    <img data-u="image" src="/demos/img/travel/01.jpg" border="0" style="width: 720px; height: 480px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;">
                    <img data-u="thumb" src="/demos/img/travel/thumb-01.jpg" style="display: none;">
                    <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 720px; height: 480px; z-index: 1000; display: none;">
                        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(/theme/img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-p="150.00" style="width: 720px; height: 480px; top: 0px; left: -720px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; perspective: 150px;">
                    <img data-u="image" src="/demos/img/travel/02.jpg" border="0" style="width: 720px; height: 480px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;">
                    <img data-u="thumb" src="/demos/img/travel/thumb-02.jpg" style="display: none;">
                    <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 720px; height: 480px; z-index: 1000; display: none;">
                        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(/theme/img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

as you can see the second line (the line before the first div with data-attribute 150.00) generated dynamically

```
<div style="width: 720px; height: 480px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; display: none; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
```

**I need to add a class to this div, but I can't find where it generates**

please help to find it and add a class to it!

Comment: How are we supposed to find it? You've given us nothing to go on

Comment: but I put the link of gallery at the first line!

Comment: Yeah, I can guarantee nobody wants to sift through source code for you when you have `ctrl+f` at your finger tips

Comment: but I dont think ctrl+f is my answer because I do it before and no success

Comment: it's not as simple as you think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use jquery to select div and add class

```
$('div[data-u="slides"]').children(":first").addClass('my-Class');
```

this will add my-Class to

```
<div style="width: 720px; height: 480px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; display: none; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
```

this div

Comment: thanks @Shree29, but I don't want to add class to div with data-p,
I want to add class to this div

but I dont know how can I access to it
i only can see it in inspect element
<div style="width: 720px; height: 480px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; display: none; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>

Comment: I mean the div just before first <div data-p="150.00     but as I said i can see it only in inspect element

Comment: @user3250818 see the answer above this might help you